# voiceChannel.ConnectAsync() throws error in Discord Client with Slashcommands

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I conncet via `var audioClient = await voiceChannel.ConnectAsync();` to the selected channel. The Bot connects and throws `Unknwon OpCode(Hello)`. Normally you can ignore that but together with Slashcommands I get the message back from the Bot directly in Discord `The application is not responding` but the Bot joins and does his tasks succesfully.

Where could be the problem here?

I broke down the error to the ConnectAsny() method. Without it I won't get the response from the bot.

Answer (score 0):

There was a change to the Discord Api:

**IP Discovery Upcoming Change**

> We recently pushed out a change related to Voice Connections that broke apps sending 70-byte UDP packets to the voice server when using IP Discovery. While the documentation and deprecation were updated in December 2019, there wasn't communication around the the change starting to roll out so we've temporarily reverted the change to give developers more time to handle the breaking change.
>
> ⚠️ Starting 15 March 2023, all apps with Voice Connections using IP Discovery must send 74-byte UDP packets. IP Discovery requests sending the deprecated 70-byte packet will no longer receive a response.

> Some 3rd party libraries may be needed to be updated to support this change, so if your app uses Voice Connections and a 3rd party library, check with the maintainer(s) to see if it sends the updated packet and/or whether you need to update the library version you're using.

> Read the IP Discovery documentation for more information about the UDP packet to send: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/voice-connections#ip-discovery

**Update to newest version**

This change is fixed in the newest version of [Discord.net](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/releases/tag/3.10.0). Just update the package and you will be fine.

**Or build from source**

If you don't want to update to the newest version, you can also, as the maintainer of discord.net mentioned on his discord server, apply [this fix](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/commit/66e6329b9df0f9401008f17263fbdebbd5dd0a77)  and build from source.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).